# Curl PHP to get HLS return 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, curl, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to get HLS stream in other site, but they always return 403 Forbidden :( This is my function, it works well on localhost, but not in my server.

```
function getPage($url, $referer, $header){ 
    $timeout=30; 
    $curl = curl_init(); 
    if(strstr($referer,"://")){
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer); 
    }
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout); 
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, sprintf("Mozilla/%d.0",rand(4,5))); 
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header); 
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $html = curl_exec ($curl); 
    curl_close ($curl); 
    return $html;
}

echo getPage("http://www.wezatv.com/dooball/assp1.php", "http://www.wezatv.com/", 1);
```

Anyone can help me?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your server IP is not a IP
use curl proxy to test ,
your link `http://www.wezatv.com/dooball/assp1.php` works normally on my server

Comment: You mean Shared Host or Shared VPS in that case is not working? I run it in a Shared Hosting. um.. How about proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is 100% correct, I think the problem is your server blocked that request or the target server blocked your server's IP

- Make sure your server doesn't block the out connection on port 80
- If no firewall, could you try to execute the command "wget http://www.wezatv.com/dooball/assp1.php" to see can it download the content? If it also cannot get the content with error code is 403, it mean the server wezatv.com blocked every request from your server.

Some server temporary block every request if it found too many request in a short moment. So if you want to claw it's data, you should reduce the number of request, such as implement a delay